# JSP rendering is not working in Spring 4 and Tomcat 8.0.20

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm finding troubles when I'm trying to build an easy example of Spring web application. When I try to show the jsp file, I obtain the jsp file not rendered, like an txt file.

Thank you in advance!

I am using the latest version of Spring 4 and tomcat 8.0.20. My Java SDK and JRE is 8.0.40. This is my folder structure:

```
src/main/java:
demo
---DemoApplication.java
demo.config
----MvcConfig.java
demo.controllers
----RootController.java


src
   main
      java
      resources
      webapp
         WEB-INF
             jsp
               test.jsp
```

There is nothing in application.properties file.

Now, I'm going to show you my code:

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.20</tomcat.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

      }
}
```

**MvcConfig.java**

```
package demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
   }

}
```

**RootController.java**

```
package demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home (){
        return "test";

    }

}
```

**test.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Inferno</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>It's working!! Oh my god! I can't believe it!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you omit the two methods in your MvcConfig? Spring Boot should "configure" itself based on what it's finding on the classpath. In this case maybe it autoconfig JSLTView for you, because JSTL is on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way to do that, using the instructions that are provided within the following urls.

http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: I use Spring Boot for a web application, but with Thymeleaf instead of JSP. So saying Spring Boot is just for stand-alone applications is not true.

Comment: Spring Boot most certainly can be used for web applications - you've marked your answer as correct when really it doesn't solve your original problem - you've simply tried an entirely different approach.

Comment: @MystyxMac I corrected the mistake about spring boot, I didn't know it.

Comment: @Fluffmeister General For me, it's solved as far as I can do now that I want to do. It doesn't matter how, I can obtain jsp web pages instead of txt files. Sometimes it's better to find other way to do something that fight hard and obtaining the same result, especially in business environment.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution anyway.

Comment: I've got the same problem - no solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my case I had a servlet mapping for:
    /* 
Which will intercept requests to the jsp as well.

So I removed in web.xml, and everything worked fine

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  <!--   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> -->  <<<<
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I had the same issue, thnx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this in your pom.xml:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

FYI, the spring-boot documentation recommends avoiding JSP if possible:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html
(search for JSP on that page)

Cheers,
Marcus

Comment: Hello Marcus, thanks a lot for your quick reply.
When I used that, I obtain a maven dependency problem:

ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:8.0.20. Connect timed out

Comment: That's strange. Maybe I misspelled or something, you could copy the link directly from here and see if it works:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/8.0.20

Comment: The same problem.. I'm going to test downloading manually and adding it to my raven repository. I will post the result.

Comment: Ok, I pasted it in the maven repository and there was no error. However, when I launched the application I received the txt-like file again...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Alright. I recommend checking this out:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

There's a sample project there you could try. :)

Comment: I think I did it something wrong when I added the jar file manually. It does not work, I will try to find something to repair this using your advices. If I manage to make it work, I will post here. Thanks anyway!